# Cannot see std::string change in another thread visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2012

I am doing something like this:

```
struct MyClass::Impl {
   std::string someString;

   //Invoked from thread "anotherThread"
   void callback() {
      std::cout << someString << std::endl;
   }
};


void MyClass::DoSomething() {
   //Connnect callback and fire operation in another thread
   anotherThread.Start(); 

   anotherThread.Op1();

   //Wait to finish without joining, Op1 invokes callback from another thread
   //...

   //string written in main thread
   impl->someString = someOtherString;

   anotherThread.Op2();
   //Wait to finish without joining, Op2 invokes callback from anotherThread
}
```

The problem is that I cannot see `impl->someString` change in callback, even if it has been written to. Do I need any additional synchronization? Callback only reads, but never writes that string.

Comment: _'Do I need any additional synchronization?'_ Of course ...

Comment: Yes, but only reading from one thread. I think it's not visible yet. How should I force the refresh?

Comment: What about notifying the other thread, when `callback()` should be called, e.g. using something like a condition variable.

Comment: I wanted to keep my code as high level as possible. I will try that, but, is it the only way?

Answer (score 3):

When writing a value in one thread and accessing the value in another thread you need to have appropriate synchronization. Without proper synchronization in both threads you have a data race. Any data race causes your program to have undefined behavior.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Here it is (it only has two items): 1. Is synchronization needed when writing in one thread and accessing in another? Answer: Yes. 2. Really? I only want to... and slow and ... Answer: yes, really. No exception.

Comment: Actually seems quite basic and I knew. The problem is I don't know the recommended way to do it for one reader and one writer.

Comment: A mutex lock would work. Given that you are monitoring a change of string you probably won't get away cheaper anyway.